# What's the difference between Error and NSError in Swift?

Tags: swift3, error-handling, nserror

I am creating a library that should return errors so I'm  wondering which one should use for my purposes.

**UPDATE:**
I should clarify, the returned result will be from a asynchronous call so I need to inform to the user if there was an error and I would like to know which type I should use Error or NSError.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`NSError` is a Cocoa **class**

> An `NSError` object encapsulates information about an error condition in an extendable, object-oriented manner. It consists of a predefined error domain, a domain-specific error code, and a user info dictionary containing application-specific information.

`Error` is a Swift **protocol** which classes, structs and enums can and `NSError` does conform to.

> A type representing an error value that can be thrown.
>
> Any type that declares conformance to the `Error` protocol can be used to represent an error in Swift’s error handling system. Because the `Error` protocol has no requirements of its own, you can declare conformance on any custom type you create.

The quoted parts are the subtitle descriptions in the documentation.

The *Swift’s error handling system* is the pattern to catch errors using `try - catch`. It requires that the error to be caught is `thrown` by a method. This pattern is much more versatile than the traditional error handling using `NSError` instances. If you're planning **not** to implement `try - catch` you actually don't need the `Error` protocol.

Comment: Interesting so then I should use Error protocol as the type for returning errors from my library.

Comment: If you are planning methods which **throws** errors, then yes.

Comment: well in my case, it will be closures that will have an argument as an error.

Comment: I understand but as far as I know __try - catch__ doesn't work for asynchronous calls so that's why I intend to use an error as an argument.

Comment: I wrote *you don't need it* but of course you can use it.

Comment: mr. vadian thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: wasn't errorType the protocol? What's the diff between errorType & error?

Comment: `ErrorType` -> Swift 2, `Error` -> Swift 3 @Honey

Comment: Or if you want to use Result