# Why struct can use 'switch case'?

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement

Looking at the below code:

```
public override func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
    
    if let urlError = error as? URLError {
        switch urlError.code {
        case .cancelled:
            print("cancelled")
        case .badURL:
            print("badURL")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The first question:

`URLError` hasn't a property `code`. It only has a public Struct `Code`.

[image]

So why can use `urlError.code`.

The second question:
`URLError.Code` is a struct. It has many static property, the code likes below:

[image]

It isn't an enum. So why can use syntax `case .cancelled:`.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that `switch` can only be used with enums? From the [Swift Programming Language book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html), _"A switch statement considers a value and compares it against several possible matching patterns."_. Regarding the first question, it is hard to answer since you haven't included the full definition of URLError. And **don't** post images of code, post it as text

Comment: @JoakimDanielson [URLError](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror) is a Foundation class. The docs say it doesn't have a member `code`

Comment: @JeremyP It wasn't clear from the question but in that case then `code` is defined in `NSError`

Comment: I can't find the relationship between `URLError` and `NSError`. So where does the member `code` defined.@JoakimDanielson @JeremyP

Comment: I have known the reason from [NSError.swift document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSError.swift). `URLError` conform the protocol  `_BridgedStoredNSError` and this protocol has a member `code`.@JeremyP

Answer (score 1):

> So why can use urlError.code

According [to documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error) `Error` conforms type `NSError` and `NSError` has property `code`, that's why you can use `code`

> It isn't an enum

`urlError.code` has type `URLError.Code` and this type conforms protocol `RawRepresentable` (you can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rawrepresentable)), that's why you can use `switch-case` as for enum

Comment: Can The protocol  `Error` conforms the class `NSError`. Can you give me some documentation which introduce the relationship of `Error` `URLError` and `NSError`.@Vadim Nikolaev

Comment: I would recommend [official Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/error). Here you can see relationship with NSError, also you can read good info about Error and NSError [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40179552/5928311) @dowZhang

Comment: I have known the reason from [NSError.swift document](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/NSError.swift). `URLError` conform the protocol  `_BridgedStoredNSError` and this protocol has a member `code`.@Vadim Nikolaev