# Cast to Error fails, but cast to NSError succeds

Tags: swift, casting, nserror, swift-optionals

In the userInfo of my notification, there is an error key, which contains an NSError

however casting it to Error fails and NSError successes

This code does NOT pass

```
        guard let error = notification.userInfo?["error"] as? Error else {
            return
        }
```

This code passes

```
        guard let nserror = notification.userInfo?["error"] as? NSError else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let error = nserror as? Error else {
            return
        }
```

I see no reason for such oddness, besides a bug in Swift? can somebody share some light on this?

Comment: This might help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40179552/5255016

Comment: i am aware of the NSError and Error difference, however, i don't understand this behavior above